# is valueHasMutated() the right way to enable validation

Tags: validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have an input field with validation:

```
var vm = {
    email:ko.observable().extend({required:true})
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);

<form>
    <input type="email" data-bind="value:email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I submit form without ever typing any value to the email field, the validation is not triggered. To trigger it I use the following:

```
vm.email.valueHasMutated();
```

Is there a better approach to trigger validation rules?

Comment: Whenever I see that someone uses valueHasMutated it generally is a design flaw - check this fiddle for some more direction on using form validation - http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/2971/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out your fiddle. You write _...design flaw_ - do you mean design flaw when used because of validation plug-in or in knockout in general?

Comment: Not in either of the libraries, in the way that your code is using them.

Comment: Got you, thanks! Can you please explain what is the purpose of showAllMessages() function? Does it add message to container? I don't use insertMessage and bind my error design element on viewmodel's property. However, it requires calling showAllMessages for the element to be displayed